# How can i fetch another wordpress post to my site's homepage?

Tags: wordpress, post, fetch-api, auto

Edited: My question is, how can i list another website's rss feed on my own site' homepage, such that when a visitor clicks on any of those lists,  it directs the visitor to the website i fetched those rss feeds from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emberjs to get posts from wordpress.

App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('posts', function() {
        this.resource('post', {path: ':post_id'});
    });
    
});
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('http://wordpresssite/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=?').then(function(data) {
            return data.posts.map(function(post) {
            post.body = post.content;
            return post
            });
            });
        
        }
});
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
        }
});
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    
    actions: {
        edit: function(){
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        }
        }
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('format-date', function(date){
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});
var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
Ember.Handlebars.helper('format-markdown', function(input) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});
```

index.html

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <div class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
   <a class="brand" href="#">Bloggr</a>
   <ul class="nav">
   <li>{{#link-to 'posts'}}Posts{{/link-to}}</li>
   <li>{{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   {{outlet}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  <div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row-fluid'>
  <div class='span3'>
  <table class='table'>
  <thead>
<tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
</thead>
{{#each}}
<tr><td>
{{#link-to 'post' this}}
    {{title}} <small class='muted'>by {{author.name}}</small>
    {{/link-to}}
    </td></tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="span9">
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
   {{#if isEditing}}
    {{partial 'post/edit'}}
    <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
    {{else}}
    <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
    {{/if}}
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>by {{author.name}} <small class='muted'>({{format-date date}})</small></h2>
  <hr>
  <div class='intro'>
  {{format-markdown excerpt}}
  </div>
  <div class='below-the-fold'>
  {{format-markdown body}}
  </div>
  </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">
    <p>{{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
    <p>{{input type="text" value=excerpt}}</p>
    <p>{{textarea value=body}}</p>
    
    
    </script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
<div class='about'>
<p>This is my first Ember.js website. Going to see how it all of this works</p>
</div>
</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Example I hope this helps you.

[image: Example of posts]